# Why NetFx helpers are internal?

Tags: .net, nuget

NetFx is a great set of helpers available through NuGet. But I don't get one thing: why all helpers classes are internal? How should I treat it if I need some helper from several projects?

**Update.** What I currently do is place NetFx classes in one project, make public those classes which I need and reference this assembly from my other projects. But this approach makes it difficult to update NetFx: I will have to make classes public again and again.

Comment: It is the *expected* that you change the code.  They are snippets.  You get the source code, not an assembly.

Comment: It is expected that I can debug the code and patch it if something is wrong. But is it expected I will change the code for just trivial usage?

Comment: It doesn't make difficult to update. NuGet will NEVER overwrite your modified Visibility.cs :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer: because they were explicitly [designed to be that way](http://blogs.clariusconsulting.net/kzu/introducing-netfx-or-the-end-of-common-dll-and-helpers-dll/). I.e. helpers should be internal to those parts that need them and not be dumped in a "Common.dll or Helpers.dll". The long answer with probably more background on this decision can only be provided by the (original) author.

Concerning your original question: you would probably include that helper in several projects.

If you really want them to live in a separate assembly and don't want to alter the code (changing internal to public), you could use the [InternalsVisibleTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx) attribute on that assembly, listing all your other projects/assemblies that need to use them. Not to say that this is good solution - it works explicitly against the initial design of NetFx - but at least it will spare you from manual labor when updating.

All in all I wouldn't make a green field decision for either ("common" DLL or strictly local functions). Both have their obvious pros and cons. But you didn't ask about that part of the story, i.e. it seems you have made a decision already ;-)

Comment: Sometimes I can't add the same helpers to different projects. What if project1 returns some netfx class? In this case I have to use the same project for netfx for project1 and project2 (which uses project1)

Comment: They cannot return something that is internal. So, if you need to make something public, you just define a partial class for the same, and mark it public.